# jw player - .hover() .show() - small glitch

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

my task is to have an image, and when the user hovers over it, if the images class conforms to some rules i've set, show a div, containing a flash video object over it with it's default image set as the image it covers such as to create an effect as if the player's controls appear above the image "magically".

I've done it all except for one tiny glitch I don't know how to repair:

When the hover() and show() event is triggered, the player, before "loading" the image I've set shows the default black screen which creates an unpleasant glitch. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: I see the JWPlayer initialization script takes an `image` property...any chance of preloading that before carrying on with your jQuery instructions? Not sure if this helps...

Comment: it is preloaded as it is the image i am covering with the player.

Comment: Hmmm...if it's the exact-same URL, it sounds like it might be a initialization-type thing with the JW Player script. Tried fading in the player just enough to make the image display, but not enough to see yet?

Comment: yes, tried that, didnt work good either unless the delay is too long and tbh it's not the way it's meant to be design-wise :)

Comment: Yea, absolutely! And putting the player behind the original image, such that you can just fade out the original image to see the player vs. fading in the player?

Comment: that could work but as i said, i need them to appear "automagically" and instantly, (boss is kinda weird with design) ;) if it was my choice that could very well be the answer hehe

Comment: even did it with z-index just now. It seems that when the player is displayed on the screen either through .show() or setting it's height from 0 to the correct number or by z-index, the starting image delays a tiny bit. frustrating!

Comment: ok managed to avoiding the glitch by actually avoiding the .show() .hide() events overall and instead pushing the objects 5000px out of the screen and thus bypassing the problem. Case closed :)